# Inner product between Fourier basis vectors - numerical calculation

Tags: python, dft

## Background

I was working through a DSP MOOC in the evenings and was presented with a question regarding the Fourier basis functions.  Initially I tried to test my hypothesis with the quick python script below however, this did not produce the answer I was expecting (the accumulated total should be approximately equal to the length of the series N).

I derived the solution mathematically just to convince myself of the correct answer.  I figured you guys would be able to quickly recognise where I've gone wrong.

---

## Proposition

Consider the fourier basis spanning $C^N$ $\{\textbf{w}_N^k\}_{k=0,...,N-1}$, where $\textbf{w}_N^k[n]=e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk}$ for $0\le n\le N-1$.

I assert the fourier basis is orthogonal and more specifically:

$\langle \textbf{w}^k, \textbf{w}^l \rangle =
\begin{cases}
    N & \text{ for }      k=l\\
    0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

---

### numerical confirmation (*?*)

```py
import numpy as np
N = 4
k = 1
l = k
total = 0.0

for n in np.arange(N):
    w_k = np.exp( 1.0j*2*np.pi*float(n*k)/float(N))
    w_l = np.exp(-1.0j*2*np.pi*float(n*l)/float(N))
    total+= w_k**w_l

print(total) #assert total ~= 4
```

### mathematical solution for $k=l$ case

$
\langle \textbf{w}_N^k, \textbf{w}_N^l \rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}n(k-l)} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^0 = N
$

### mathematical solution for $k\ne l$ case

$
\langle \textbf{w}_N^k, \textbf{w}_N^l \rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}n(k-l)} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}pn} \text{ where } p\in\mathbb{Z}
$
using the following geometric series with $r=\textbf{w}_N^p$...
$\boxed{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}r^n = \frac{1-r^N}{1-r}}$ so $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\textbf{w}_N^{np} = \frac{1-\textbf{w}_N^{Np}}{1-\textbf{w}_N^{p}}$

numerator is $0$ given $\textbf{w}_N^{Np}=1$ hence $\langle \textbf{w}_N^k, \textbf{w}_N^l \rangle = 0$ for $k\ne l$

Comment: Shouldn't it be `np.arange(N)`?

Comment: yep - sorry, this was just an ham fisted attempt to pull out the right number.  Edited - but the issue still stands

Comment: Your math is fine. Your code is wrong. Why are you using the `**` operator here ?

Comment: Silly me, problem solved. I don't know where that came from. A very late night of doing online courses.  Thanks a lot